# Is the SonarQube Java analyser supposed to be able to analyse semantically incorrect Java source code?

Tags: java, sonarqube

Given the following java source code,

```
public class Test {
  private static int a;
  private static int a;
}
```

you will run into an error while analyzing, is it expected? I think it should be log as a parser failure, not to stop the analysis, right?

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '/home/administrator/tmp/frameworks/av/Test.java'
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:75)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:131)
    at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:124)
    at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:86)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:59)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:51)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.execute(DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.java:120)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:264)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:220)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:135)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:158)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: duplicate key: a
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:115)
    at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.<init>(RegularImmutableMap.java:72)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.fromEntryList(ImmutableMap.java:221)
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.build(ImmutableMap.java:207)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.HiddenFieldCheck.visitNode(HiddenFieldCheck.java:94)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:89)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:115)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:91)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:72)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionVisitor.java:65)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.SubscriptionBaseVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionBaseVisitor.java:33)
    at org.sonar.java.checks.HiddenFieldCheck.scanFile(HiddenFieldCheck.java:80)
    at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:123)
    at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:94)
    ... 38 more
```

Answer (score 3):

This source code can't be compiled and so we also don't expect the SonarQube Java analyser to be able to analyse this piece of code. But the error message should be a bit more meaningful. I've created the following Jira ticket: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1182

Comment: things are a bit more complex than just an error message. Here the stacktrace indicates that failure happened during a check and not during semantic analysis (where it should fail) 
I'll update the ticket with a comment about this.

Comment: Yes, that's what i mean, when analyzing such source code, you should report a parser error, not to stop the analyzing.

Comment: @MaksonLee no, we should definitely fail the analysis IMO (and this is really something opiniated here) : what is the point of analyzing a code that is not compilable ? 
My point is that the failure should happen more nicely and earlier in the analysis (during semantic).
Please note also that this is not a parse error, this is a semantic issue (Syntactically your code is valid).

Comment: @benzonico, what i mean is, you have many Java source code in a project, you should keep analyze the rest of, not to stop the analyzing.

Comment: In other words, you should try to catch and handle this kind of error, not to exit the runner.

Comment: This kind of member name duplication can be obtained not by compilation but from an obfuscation tool like Proguard.
Sonar was not able to analyze my project with a third-party library processed with a proguard -overloadaggresively option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622192