# Is the SonarQube Java analyser supposed to be able to detect "duplicate local variable" error?

Tags: sonarqube

Create the follow Java class in Eclipse, it will say that there is a duplicate local variable error,

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hello();
    }

    private static void hello() {
        int a=1;
        int a=1;
    }
}
```

then you analyze this Java class with SonarQube, it can be analyzed without any problem, shouldn't a semantic issue be reported?

```
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1.1
21:46:51.395 INFO  - Load global repositories
21:46:51.609 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=218ms
21:46:51.611 INFO  - Server id: 20150702122849
21:46:51.614 INFO  - User cache: /home/administrator/.sonar/cache
21:46:51.622 INFO  - Install plugins
21:46:51.700 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
21:46:51.707 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar
21:46:53.026 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
21:46:54.946 INFO  - Load project repositories
21:46:55.036 INFO  - Load project repositories (done) | time=91ms
21:46:55.036 INFO  - Load project settings
21:46:55.400 INFO  - Load technical debt model
21:46:55.427 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
21:46:55.700 INFO  - -------------  Scan test/platform/frameworks/av
21:46:55.710 INFO  - Load module settings
21:46:55.897 INFO  - Load rules
21:46:56.119 INFO  - Base dir: /home/administrator/tmp/frameworks/av
21:46:56.119 INFO  - Working dir: /home/administrator/tmp/frameworks/av/.sonar
21:46:56.120 INFO  - Source paths: .
21:46:56.121 INFO  - Source encoding: ISO-8859-2, default locale: en_US
21:46:56.121 INFO  - Index files
21:46:56.344 INFO  - 1 files indexed
21:46:56.390 INFO  - Quality profile for java: Sonar way
21:46:56.424 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor
21:46:57.107 INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan...
21:46:57.112 INFO  - 1 source files to be analyzed
21:46:57.416 INFO  - Java Main Files AST scan done: 309 ms
21:46:57.417 INFO  - 1/1 source files have been analyzed
21:46:57.417 WARN  - Java bytecode has not been made available to the analyzer. The org.sonar.java.bytecode.visitor.DependenciesVisitor@51e55964, org.sonar.java.checks.UnusedPrivateMethodCheck@431dc52b, org.sonar.java.checks.RedundantThrowsDeclarationCheck@7fa7f0c8 are disabled.
21:46:57.417 INFO  - Java Test Files AST scan...
21:46:57.418 INFO  - 0 source files to be analyzed
21:46:57.418 INFO  - Java Test Files AST scan done: 1 ms
21:46:57.418 INFO  - 0/0 source files have been analyzed
21:46:57.443 INFO  - Sensor JavaSquidSensor (done) | time=1019ms
21:46:57.443 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
21:46:57.445 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=2ms
21:46:57.445 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor
21:46:57.450 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=5ms
21:46:57.450 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor
21:46:57.472 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor (done) | time=22ms
21:46:57.473 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor
21:46:57.487 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor (done) | time=14ms
21:46:57.487 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor
21:46:57.518 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=31ms
21:46:57.518 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor
21:46:57.520 INFO  - parsing /home/administrator/tmp/frameworks/av/target/surefire-reports
21:46:57.520 ERROR - Reports path not found or is not a directory: /home/administrator/tmp/frameworks/av/target/surefire-reports
21:46:57.520 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor (done) | time=2ms
21:46:57.520 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
21:46:57.520 INFO  - SCM provider for this project is: git
21:46:57.529 INFO  - 1 files to be analyzed
21:46:57.910 INFO  - 0/1 files analyzed
21:46:57.910 WARN  - Missing blame information for the following files:
21:46:57.911 WARN  -   * /home/administrator/tmp/frameworks/av/Test.java
21:46:57.911 WARN  - This may lead to missing/broken features in SonarQube
21:46:57.911 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=391ms
21:46:57.911 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor
21:46:57.911 INFO  - JavaCpdEngine is used for java
21:46:57.912 INFO  - Cross-project analysis disabled
21:46:57.939 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=28ms
21:46:57.941 INFO  - No quality gate is configured.
21:46:57.985 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2015-07-03)
21:46:57.992 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2015-06-03, analysis of Thu Jul 02 14:53:26 CST 2015)
21:46:58.311 INFO  - Execute decorators...
21:46:58.960 INFO  - Store results in database
21:46:59.289 INFO  - Analysis reports generated in 44ms, dir size=1 KB
21:46:59.299 INFO  - Analysis reports compressed in 10ms, zip size=1 KB
21:46:59.349 INFO  - Analysis reports sent to server in 50ms
21:46:59.350 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard/index/test-platform-frameworks-av
21:46:59.350 INFO  - Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report.
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the SonarQube Java analyser supposed to be able to analyse semantically incorrect Java source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178940/is-the-sonarqube-java-analyser-supposed-to-be-able-to-analyse-semantically-incor)

Comment: No, in this case, no any error was thrown while analyzing.

Comment: What compiler do you use? I would expect a compiler error on something like that. I use Sonar on classes, so in my case, build fails and sonar is not ran at all.

Comment: In my case, we only analyze Java source code, not binary.

Comment: This is the exact same case, the sonarqube java analyzer is  expected to fail on semantic analysis  if code is not compilable like your case. 
If you only analyze sources you are likely to get far more accurate result. Moreover, this is not related to the fact that it does not seem relevant to analyze code that is not compilable/compiled in the first place as pointed out by @Vlasec.

Comment: So in this case, a semantic analysis error should be thrown?

Comment: Yes, indeed as stated in jira ticket linked in the other post.

Comment: Thanks, it would be great if sonarqube can detect semantic and syntatic error.